# Need to refactor to use both GoChevronDown and GoChevronLeft

Tags: reactjs

So I have a DropDown component that I need to refactor to use `GoChevronDown` and `GoChevronLeft` depending upon the user clicking the Select label, I have tried this on my own and I continue to just get a blank screen:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { GoChevronDown } from "react-icons/go";

function Dropdown({ options, value, onChange }) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  const handleOptionClick = (option) => {
    // CLOSE DROPDOWN
    setIsOpen(false);
    // WHAT OPTION DID THE USER CLICK ON??
    onChange(option);
  };

  const renderedOptions = options.map((option) => {
    return (
      <div
        className='hover:g-sky-100 rounded cursor-pointer p-1'
        onClick={() => handleOptionClick(option)}
        key={option.value}
      >
        {option.label}
      </div>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className='w-48 relative'>
      <div
        className='flex justify-between items-center cursor-pointer border rounded p-2 shadow bg-white w-full'
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        {value?.label || "Select..."} <GoChevronDown className='text-3xl' />
      </div>
      {isOpen && (
        <div className='absolute top-full border rounded p-3 shadow bg-white w-full'>
          {renderedOptions}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Dropdown;
```

I thought I would add an `index` to the mapping function and then compare that index to `isOpen`.

I also developed an icon variable where I placed some span tags with both chevron icons.

I figured I had to put some of the elements in the second return statement inside the mapping function, but no matter how I do it I just get a blank screen.

So I have a minimal reproducible example here of what I attempted:

https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-wind-f6dkd5?file=/src/components/Dropdown.js

But you will see that it does not look right.

There should be a Select... with an icon to the right and when you click on it some items dropdown, "red", "green", "blue" to be exact.

Comment: Could you include any errors you're getting, or even better a [mre]?

Comment: @0stone0, sure here is the minimal reproducible example: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-wind-f6dkd5?file=/src/components/Dropdown.js

Comment: HUh you're never using `setExpandedIndex`?

Comment: @0stone0, sorry thats an old version, I ended up removing that useState hook. Please refresh the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was going for:

```
return (
    <div className='w-48 relative'>
      <div
        className='flex justify-between items-center cursor-pointer border rounded p-2 shadow bg-white w-full'
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        {value?.label || "Select..."}
        {isOpen ? (
          <GoChevronDown className='text-3xl' />
        ) : (
          <GoChevronLeft className='text-3xl' />
        )}
      </div>
      {isOpen && (
        <div className='absolute top-full border rounded p-3 shadow bg-white w-full'>
          {renderedOptions}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

With this refactor, the `Dropdown` component will display the `GoChevronDown` icon when the dropdown is clicked and the `GoChevronLeft` icon when the dropdown is not clicked. This is what I was going for, but it was a struggle to figure it out, writing JS in JSX can be sometimes painful for me. My apologies for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already holding the selected item in a useState in `<App>`, you could use that value to check if the icon should be opened or closed.

---

```
const isExpanded = option.value === value?.value;
```

Since `option.value` hold the current option from the iteration, and `value.value` will hold the selected value, no need to keep track of the 'selected index'

---

Regarding OP's comment, if you want the `icon` to only show it with the 'select', you can move it next to the select using a fragment and an if/else that will choose between `value.label` or `Select + icon`

```
{
  (value) 
    ? value.label 
    : <React.Fragment>
        {"Select..."}
        "LEFT"
      </React.Fragment>
}
```

---

Small demo from your fiddle
<sub>With some minor changes to make it work here in a SO snippet</sub>

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Dropdown({ options, value, onChange }) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  const handleOptionClick = (option) => {
    // CLOSE DROPDOWN
    setIsOpen(false);
    // WHAT OPTION DID THE USER CLICK ON??
    onChange(option);
  };

  const renderedOptions = options.map((option) => {
    return (
      <div
        className="hover:g-sky-100 rounded cursor-pointer p-1"
        onClick={() => handleOptionClick(option)}
        key={option.value}
      >
        {option.label}
      </div>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className="w-48 relative">
      <div
        className="flex justify-between items-center cursor-pointer border rounded p-2 shadow bg-white w-full"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        {
          value 
            ? value.label 
            : <React.Fragment>
                {"Select..."}
                "LEFT"
              </React.Fragment>
        }
      </div>
      {isOpen && (
        <div className="absolute top-full border rounded p-3 shadow bg-white w-full">
          {renderedOptions}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

const Example = () => {

    const [selection, setSelection] = useState(null);

    const handleSelect = (option) => {
      setSelection(option);
    };

    const options = [
      { label: "Red", value: "red" },
      { label: "Green", value: "green" },
      { label: "Blue", value: "blue" }
    ];
    return (
      <Dropdown options={options} value={selection} onChange={handleSelect} />
    );
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: that works to make the chevrons put down and left depending on a click, but I do not want a chevron to the right of every item in the dropdown just the "Select..."

Comment: Updated my answer, not sure if I understood correctly tho, please let me know otherwise!

Comment: so what I dont want is those icons next to the items, I only want the icon next to "Select..."

Comment: You are only rendering `Select` if there is no selected value, so seems like you could do `{value ? value.label : <React.Fragment>{"Select..."}{icon}</React.Fragment>}`

Comment: unless I put it together wrong, it just gives me Red Red Red

Comment: I refactored the minimal reproducible, it now looks exactly like I want it, but I want the arrow button to point down in other words switch over to `GoChevronDown` when `Select...` is clicked. Hopefully that will be more straightforward, sorry for any confusion.

Comment: So if you click an option ,there should be no icon anymore? If so, my edit should work. If you want an icon only on the first option ,you'll need to combine it with open state